# Excluding mesh from UV map

Tags: texturing, uv

I need to add some new details to an existing project that's already UV mapped.
To be more specific I need to add glasses to the canopy of an aircraft. The aircraft has been mapped from the original mesh designer and I'm not an expert in **Blender** to remap the whole project.
I successfully add the *glass* elements to the canopy but they are mapped with a weird pattern.
This's the result:

[image: Weird mappings]

I tried to modify the material assignement to such mesh with no result.
The full project is [here](https://github.com/weirdgyn/Folgore). Items to be exluded from mapping are: `canopy.glass` and `cockpit.glass`.
Of course the new material to assign to such items should be transparent.

Comment: Hi! Your question is a little bit confusing.
What do you want this to look like ?
I mean... can't you just assign a new material with a transparency if you want the canopy to look transparent?

Comment: since your using eeve, you might run into some issues regarding the transparency.
I would suggest watching some tutorials about transparency in eeve and also about light map baking if you want to get best results.

Comment: @Nand27 of course I tried but as long as I can see if I assign a transparent material to this nothin happens (but of course I'm probably doing something wrong)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. The problem was given from the useless stack of materials applied to every mesh (also to newly created ones?!) ... I needed to empty object materials stack and then the transparent material worked (on Cycles of course...) right now I'm looking a tutorial about glass material in EEVEE as Nand27 suggested. thnx.